# How to disable Alfresco workflow menu?

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I want to disable the workflow menu in Alfresco Community 5.2. I've added in `alfresco-global.properties`:

```
system.workflow.engine.activiti.enabled=false
```

but nothing has changed.

Comment: You mean, you don't want to show'Tasks' menu from the main menu?

Comment: The 'system.workflow.engine.activiti.enabled' property is used to switch between activiti or jbpm engines.
You need to do share customization to hide the workflow menu.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do one or more Share customizations to remove workflow-related menu items from the places you no longer want them to be available. You should start by learning how to make [Aikau customizations to Share](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-custom-share-header-menu.html).